# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time with this. This is the code im working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jfdbz/

```
$(function () {
    var lastQuery  = null,
        lastResult = null, // new!
        autocomplete,
        processLocation = function (input, lat, long, callback) { // accept a callback argument
            var query = $.trim(input.val()),
                geocoder;

            // if query is empty or the same as last time...
            if (!query || query === lastQuery) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(lastResult); // send the same result as before
                }
                return; // and stop here
            }

            lastQuery = query; // store for next time

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({address: query}, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                    long.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    lastResult = true; // success!
                } else {
                    alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
                    lastResult = false; // failure!
                }
                if (callback) {
                    callback(lastResult); // send the result back
                }
            });
        },
        ctryiso = $("#ctry").val(),
        options = {
            types: ["geocode"]
        };

    if (ctryiso !== '') {
        options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': ctryiso };        
    }
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#loc")[0], options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);

    $('#search').click(function (e) {
        var form = $(this).closest('form'),
            input = $("#loc"),
            lat = $("#lat"),
            lng = $("#lng");
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

        processLocation(input, lat, lng, function (success) {
            if (success) { // if the geocoding succeeded, submit the form
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });

    $('#geosearch').click(function (e) {
        var form = $(this).closest('form'),
            input = $("#geoloc"),
            lat = $("#geolat"),
            lng = $("#geolng");
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

        processLocation(input, lat, lng);
    });
});
```

When the autosuggestion link is clicked it should geocode the result in the first and second example. However when I click on a autosuggest option from the dropdown I get the following error on line 39:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined

Can anyone help pinpoint where I am going wrong here please?

EDIT: To replicate I do the following:

- Open up javascript console in Chrome
- Type in a few letters into the location box on the top line
- Click on a suggested location from the drop down

Apparently according to my editor line 39 says this:

if (ctryiso !== '') {

Comment: It's hard to tell just from your pasted code; which is line 39? If your code editor doesn't show it to the left, Bing for "`[name of your IDE] enable line numbers"

Comment: Put a break point on that line and see what the values are.

Comment: can you give us detailed step on how to replicate error? its very hard to replicate error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.maps.event.addListener` will not pass the parameters to the function you provided(`processLocation`) so you need to create new function for it.

```
process = function () {
    var input = $("#loc"),
        lat = $("#lat"),
        lng = $("#lng");
    processLocation(input, lat, lng, null);
}
```

and call it like,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', process);
```

then it will works like this,

http://jsfiddle.net/Jfdbz/6/

***UPDATE,***

---

Here is a more cleaner way as you requested.
http://jsfiddle.net/Jfdbz/9/

Change the `processLocation` like this,

```
processLocation = function (callback) { // accept a callback argument
            var input = $("#loc"),
                lat = $("#lat"),
                long = $("#lng");
            // rest of the cocde ***
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It seems to work but at the same time it adds more bloat to the code, so I will go with this unless there is a cleaner way to do it

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I don't need the elements in the form to be called anything different, as long is the form is different all the leements can be called loc, lng, lat. I changed it which I think is what your example was pointing to but the second form still doesnt work. Am I doing something wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Jfdbz/10/

Comment: Do you really need to have two forms in the same page?

Comment: No they will never be on the same page, I just wanted to show them functioning side by side. Really i'd like the id's of the fields the same, but have it so it geocodes or submits the form based on either the id of the button or the form id which contains it all

Comment: so then make them like same. same stucture same id's then it will works http://jsfiddle.net/Jfdbz/11/.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);
```

That callback is being called with no arguments thus `input` is undefined and therefore you can't call `val()` on it in line 6.

Instead do this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed',function(){
    processLocation(arguments); //With whatever arguments you need
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to see an example of this?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jfdbz/8/ You should really look at cleaning it up a bit as well. Use Javascript's data structures (objects, arrays etc) to define constants and to separate dom manipulation and selection to allow cleaner and more reusable code.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see, this

```
$('#search').click(function (e) {
    var form = $(this).closest('form'),
        input = $("#loc"),
        lat = $("#lat"),
        lng = $("#lng");
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

    processLocation(input, lat, lng, function (success) {
        if (success) { // if the geocoding succeeded, submit the form
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

defines the lat, lng etc variables with scope function, so you can not reference those in other functions like

```
 geocoder.geocode({address: query}, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                long.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
```

try to define them outside:

```
 var lastQuery  = null,
    lastResult = null, // new!
    autocomplete,
    lat = null,
    lng = null ...
```

and then use as this:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form'),
    input = $("#loc"); // !!
// no var here:
    lat = $("#lat");
    lng = $("#lng");
```